# Is certain opening determine relative pieces value

Tags: analysis

as I know that certain opening will leads to certain positions, but I do not know if certain opening will determine relative value of chess pieces. Are there some sources to explained it??

as example :
if I choose Ruy Lopez, my knights will more worth than my bishops, and etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To some extent, yes. General rule: if certain opening/variant of opening will leads to open position, then bishops will be worth more than knights - and usually opposite in closed games.

Comment: I'd like to see some source to explained it.. but some expert word should be enough..